# Service load is high - service_process listed in top

Tags: linux, ps, top, alma-linux

I can't find any information on *service_process* which appears intermittently when server load is high.

Is there any information about this process? Is there a way to see which other process is using the *service_process*?

```
top - 10:00:51 up 24 days,  1:25, 31 users,  load average: 5.62, 2.49, 1.79
Tasks: 2328 total,   1 running, 2327 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 20.9 us,  7.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 61.8 id,  8.4 wa,  0.9 hi,  0.4 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15738.9 total,   4589.5 free,   2604.0 used,   8545.5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   7632.0 total,   7075.9 free,    556.1 used.   8710.8 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2564694 root      30  10  769428 531116 122904 S 168.2   3.3   0:19.88 service_process
2568877 root      20   0   56772   6824   3704 R  27.3   0.0   0:00.13 top
   1469 mysql     20   0 5092972 605160  17492 S   9.1   3.8   1745:06 mysqld
```

Comment: ps -ef will show you the parent process id and you can filter with service_process PID with grep in your case ps -ef | grep 2564694

Comment: Is Acronis backup on the machine?